# How can I bind a C# WPF TextBox to different properties depending on a condition?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

How can I tell my TextBox to bind to different properties depending on user selection.  My scenario is:

A customer has these properties:

1. Mailing Address and
2. Shipping Address.

When editing or creating these, there is a radio button for selecting which address to edit.  So when I click the Mailing Address radio button, I want to bind my TextBox to the property "`MailAddress`", but when the Shipping Address is clicked, I want to change the binding to the "`ShipAddress`" property.

I know I can have a property "`Address`" that gets set when the radio button is clicked, but I want to bind directly to `Customer.MailAddress` or `Customer.ShipAddress` for validation purposes (Mail address is required, but ship address is not).

Comment: Dude, handle this at the ViewModel level. put a property called `public string TextToShow` in the ViewModel and set that according to your logic. keep it simple.

Comment: @HighCore Could be wrong, but I don't think he's working on MVVM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I'd like to say that I wouldn't do this myself, but to answer your question directly, here is how you could do this:

```
<TextBox Name="YourTextBox">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="{Binding MailAddress}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TheRadioButton}" 
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="{Binding ShipAddress}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

I would personally just throw these controls into a `UserControl` that I could bind to, or even double up my controls, hard coding all of my `Binding`s and then use the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property value to switch the `Visibility` of them. It might result in more code, but it would be a lot cleaner and easier to debug. Either way, it's up to you.

Comment: I prefer this way because it avoids duplication. Consider what happens when you want to apply another style or handle the TextBox in code-behind -- you need to apply the style and code to both controls, whereas here you can just handle one and use Style.BasedOn (or just write the other setters inline).

Comment: I ended up just doubling up the textboxes and bound the visibility of them to whichever radio button was checked.  But the style shown did work also.  Thanks Sheridan!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest use two separate text boxes, and bind their visibility to the radio boxes, so you can bind and validate the two properties separately.

```
<Window.Resource>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisiConv"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resource>
<RadioButton Name="RdBoxMailing"/> <RadioButton Name="RdBoxShipping"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding MailAddress}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName="RdBoxMailing", Converter={StaticResource BoolVisiConv}}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ShipAddress}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName="RdBoxShipping", Converter={StaticResource BoolVisiConv}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the behind in the callback of the event Checked of your radiobutton..

Something like :

```
Binding b = new Binding("ShippingAddress");
_textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
```

Comment: sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: why does it sound like a really bad idea ?

Comment: because you don't set bindings in procedural code. Period. see my comment above. Your solution would require that the business logic used to determine what property to bind to be placed in `code behind`. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: His question was how to change the binding when the checkbox is clicked, not if it is a good idea to do so.

Comment: @franssu I'm in agreement with HighCore. It's best to stick with the MVVM pattern and not do bindings in the code-behind. Whether OP has implemented MVVM is another issue entirely, your answer might be the best option if he hasn't.